# UIScrollView Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity when using Aspect Ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I want to set a square scrollView in my nib file.
So for this reason I have pinned my scrollview to the top, left and right of the superview.

Then I'm setting the aspect ratio of the scrollView to 1:1.
However this triggers the error in IB about Ambiguity in contest size height and width of the scroll view.

Is this a bug, or am I understanding this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this *is* ambiguous :-)
For example, what do you expect from your scroll view when its superview's height changes (let's say it gets taller)?

If your answer is "to get taller as well", you don't need the 1:1 constraint.
Or, if it's "to keep the original height", the bottom space constraint is extra.

Same exercise for the width and left/right constraints.

**UPD:** Looks like the warning has disappeared in the new Xcode (6A1052d); trying to check that in comments below.

Comment: I'm expecting a square UIScrollView, so I want the height of the UIScrollView to change only when the width of the superview changes. That's why I added the 1:1 constraint. I don't have a bottom space constraint set.

Comment: Hmm, are you able to reproduce this in the latest Xcode? I've updated mine last night and can't see the warning anymore :-\

Comment: Seems to be the case — just opened that project in an outdated beta, and it's still there.

Comment: Updating now and will let you know. Hopefully it's fixed!

Comment: Interesting... Here's my XIB: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2330560/ScrollViewSample.xib — do you see the warning there?

Comment: It was a subview that I had placed inside the UIScrollView that caused this (a UIActivityIndicator). Looks like centering an object inside an element that has Aspect Ratio is considered by the Interface builder ambiguous, which though is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue.

It was a subview that I had placed inside the UIScrollView that caused this (a UIActivityIndicator). Looks like centering an element inside an element that has with or height set based on Aspect Ratio is considered by the Interface builder ambiguous, which though is wrong.

I will file in a report for this.